# Get information from Wikipedia chart using Applescript

Tags: applescript, wikipedia

I am talking about pages like this one:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetone
I would like to get info from the chart that stores Density, Molar Mass, Boiling Point, etc. I need the program to store the info in separate strings. Yes not variables, so:

```
vapor_pressure = "24.46"
```

Not:

```
vapor_pressure = 24.46
```

This is because I need to to be typed in again somewhere else, but I've got that part down. 
Also, how do I get it to remove all characters from the string, except numbers and decimal points? Thats pretty much all I need.

Comment: http://macosxautomation.com/applescript/sbrt/index.html , see Topic "HTML Routines"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by getting the html of the entire page:

```
import bs4
import urllib2
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetone).read())
```

Converted it to text:

```
page = soup.get_text()
```

Then when I printed `page` I found that the properties were separated by two line breaks:

```
list1 = page.split('\n\n')
```

To grab just the string with vapor pressure:

```
vaporpressure = [x for x in list1 if "Vapor pressure" in x]
```

Then when I print `vaporpressure` I got something like:

```
Vapor pressure
24.46–24.60 kPa (at 20 °C)
```

Thats what I did.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [MediaWiki API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aMain_page):

`do shell script "curl -s 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&titles=Acetone'|sed -n 's/^|  VaporPressure = \\([0-9.]*\\).*/\\1/p'"`